# Linux libffi-3.0.11 installation issue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev, libffi

I try to install libffi-3.0.11 I followed that side

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libffi.html

But I got this error message. How can I solve that?

```
make[3]: *** [src/powerpc/ffi.lo] Error 1 
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/libffi-3.0.11/powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu' 
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/libffi-3.0.11/powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu' 
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/libffi-3.0.11/powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu' make: ***   
[all-all] Error 2
```

Comment: cut&paste make output a little higher :)

Comment: @barti_ddu:  Well, I'm a bit desperate, I just want to install udev, but by hand without package manger as a newbie... puhh not so easy

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem: I think the main issue was/is that I have a PowerPc architecture.

I used this patch http://sourceware.org/ml/libffi-discuss/2012/msg00201.html and replaced the code from the tutorial patch http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libffi.html and continued with the instructions. And lo and behold it worked.

Hopefully this will help some other developer.

Comment: @OliverStutz It seems so. And I hope I solved this rat's tail. On the other hand I got some other questions, which I have to answer now. But it's not the right place to talk about it here.